# Access a data from everywhere

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a few frames in my program.I need to access a data from everywhere how can I do this?

```
public class Main{
    public int aData;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Frame1 f = new Frame1();
    }
}

public Frame1 extends JFrame{

    // ....
    public void foo(){

        // I need aData in here.

    }

}
```

Edit 1 : I have more than one data and when one of them is updated the data in main class should be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass it in the `Frame1` constructor

```
public class Main{
    public int aData;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Frame1 f = new Frame1(aData);
    }
}

public Frame1 extends JFrame{
    private int data;
    public Frame1(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // ....
    public void foo(){
        // use data here
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you need more than just `aData` (such as `bData`, and some other things), you can instead pass it a `Main`: `Frame1 f = new Frame1(this)`, where `public Frame1(Main data) { this.myMain=data)...` -- from then on, `Frame1` can reference `myMain.whatever`.

Comment: zebediah49 nonono, that makes it far too reliant. If you want more data, pass more to the constructor. Otherwise the Frame1 class can't be reused elsewhere without whatever else wants to use it having to know about Main

Comment: There's also the issue that `aData` is declared nonstatic but `main` is static.

Answer (score 2):

The most important question is why you think you need to do this. If you truly want something accessible from anywhere, you can just make it a public static member somewhere, but this is horrible design practice.

Generally, you want to make your design modular, so each thing depends only on what it actually needs. Then you can pass it an object that provides the data it needs, such as configuration settings. This lets you mock things out easily for unit testing and the like, and reduces the amount of code you need to rewrite when making changes to the program.

Answer (score -1):

Try making Fram1 instance static

Comment: If reasonable to do otherwise, static should be avoided for this purpose.